# Flex two rows to align at the bottom without centering according to space

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to make two rows align to the bottom, without using the rest of the space to vertically align the first row.

When I only have one row it works great, but when I add another row, the first row will align vertically to make it use the rest of the space.

Basically I want the two rows to be at the bottom, because then they will align with the ones in the other containers, and make it look uniform.
The title can vary in length, so the boxes inside the content, must always flow to the bottom so they always will align.

See the picture here:

[image: Flex align bottom needs to be without space between the orange rows]

Example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zv56fak7/2/

Here it shows two rows in one line, and these should be on seperate lines, and both be aligned to the bottom without any spacing between them.
I tried to make the 'my-flex-item-content-box' inside separate rows, but it didn't work.
So I want it as shown at the picture, but just that all the oranges rows should be aligned to the bottom.

Sample code:

```css
.my-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.my-flex-item-wrapper {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
}

.my-flex-item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.my-flex-item-header {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.my-flex-item-content {
  align-items: baseline;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: inherit;
}

.my-flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.my-flex-item-content-box {
  width: 33.33%;
  min-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  background-color: purple;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-flex-item-wrapper">
  <div class="my-flex-item">
    <div class="my-flex-item-header">
      Queen and Adam Lambert 4th July Ultimate On Stage Experience
    </div>
    <div class="my-flex-item-content">
      <div class="my-flex-row">
        <div class="my-flex-item-content-box">
          Content box
        </div>
        <div class="my-flex-item-content-box">
          Content box
        </div>
        <div class="my-flex-item-content-box">
          Content box
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="my-flex-row">
        <div class="my-flex-item-content-box">
          Content box
        </div>
        <div class="my-flex-item-content-box">
          Content box
        </div>
        <div class="my-flex-item-content-box">
          Content box
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On the highest row that you want pinned to the bottom, apply `margin-top: auto`.

Comment: Or on the top row in the layout, apply `margin-bottom: auto`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
Setting '.my-flex-row' with 'with:100%;' and 'flex-basis: auto;', it gives me a row with only 3 items inside as desired.
Setting '.my-flex-item-content' with 'align-content: flex-end;' there is no spacing.

[Rows without any spacing between is working nicely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgfTb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the flex-grow property from `.my-flex-item-content` and add   `margin-top:auto;`. http://jsfiddle.net/zv56fak7/13/

```
.my-flex-item-content {
  margin-top:auto;
  align-items: baseline;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Also mind the padding and box-sizing if that is an issue

```
.my-flex-item-wrapper {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```